# Good book on combinatorics for beginners in statistical mechanics

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, book-recommendation, statistical-mechanics

Im studying stat mech and i want to have a better understanding on counting microstates. What book in combinatorics do you guys recommend for beginners like me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how helpful it will be for your specific purposes, but I found Brualdi to be a good introductory text